# Error en Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio al usar la opción "Edit top 200 Rows"

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Cuando intento correr la opcion Edit top 200 Rows en Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, me envia el siguiente error:

> **Access to the path
>   'C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpBC65.tmp.dtq' is denied.
>   (mscorlib)**

La base de datos esta una instancia de un servidor remoto, ¿qué podría ser?

Comment: Estas ejecutando el SQL Server Management Studio como admin ? usaste la opcion "Run as administrator" cuando ejecutaste el Management Studio

Comment: Si, ejecuto el Management studio como administrador, además de eso, soy administrador tanto en la pc como en el servidor, me di atributos para las carpetas tanto en server como en la pc y sigue igual, lo curioso es que cuando hago una consulta via código si la ejecuta.

Comment: que version de Sql Server estas usando? es la 2014. Si te conectas con el Management Studio desde otra pc al servicio remoto, puedes ejecutar la consulta de edicion?

Comment: @Cainah Puede ser un problema con algún proceso que esta tomando ese archivo, si reinicias tu pc y tratas de nuevo?

Comment: Leandro Tuttini: Es SQL server 2012 con el SQL Management studio también 2012, desde otra maquina no lo hace sime permite hacer las modificaciones.

Comment: Elenasys: Ya intente reiniciando el equipo y con otro usuario en el mismo y me marca lo mismo, creo que reinstalare el SQL management Studio, gracias a ambos, mañana les contare si sirvió, saludos

Comment: Pues les comento  que elimine el perfil local de windows y se soluciono el problema, al parecer  es un archivo temporal, gracias a ambos

Comment: @Cainah, puedes publicar esto como respuesta y aceptarla, para que la pregunta no quede sin una.

Comment: Eh visto que eso sucede en algunos casos cuando el Management studio es menor a la versión del Sql remoto al que se intenta conectar

Answer (score 2):

Pues les comento que elimine el perfil local de windows y se soluciono el problema, al parecer es un archivo temporal.

Answer (score 0):

Ubica el tmpBC65.tmp.dtq en otra ruta, preferiblemente que no sea el disco C

Comment: ¿Por qué? ¿En qué basas tu respuesta?

Comment: Porque muchas veces los permisos sobre la unidad C les gusta causar problemas.

Comment: @Elena te recomiendo agregar ese comentario como parte de la respuesta para que los lectores (sobretodo quienes desconocen de este tipo de problemas) puedan entender mejor la situación.

Comment: @Elena: Aun si fuera ese el problema (que lo dudo, porque usualmente no hay ningun problema de acceso accediendo el temp folder, sea en el disco C o no), ¿como pudiera OP controlar el lugar donde se ubica este archivo?  Parece ser un archivo generado automaticamente por SSMS. Si sabes como, eso sería bueno compartirlo.